# Compound words with 生

Tags: meaning

The dictionary says 生词 means "new words". I know that 词 means "word". Then I concluded that 生 would mean "new" as well as the famous meaning "birth" that it has. But I couldn't find the meaning "new" for the word 生 in the dictionary.
Could anyone help me understand how did 生 come to have "new" meaning?
I have also come across 生　somewhere else where it meant "production".
Again, I couldn't find the meaning "production" for it in the dictionary.

Comment: `生词` means 陌**生**的单**词**, and `生人` means stranger. `生肉` means raw meat. `生产` means production, I have not heard that a single `生` means production.

Answer (score 3):

生 does not mean "new". It has the meaning of "unfamiliar" (生疏，不熟悉的）. "生词" literally means unfamiliar word.

Check [zdic](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E7%94%9F).

Answer (score 0):

生 can be used for "unknown/unfamiliar things" such as 生人(an unknown person), 生面孔 (an unknown face), 陌生(unfamiliar), 陌生人(stranger).

生字 and 生词 mean a word or a phrase that is unknown to the person prior to seeing them or, been taught the first time. In this case, you can think it means "new", a new word, or a new phrase to that person.